# How to verify if published post using Facebook Graph API is set to public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way how to verify if published post using Facebook Graph API is set to public visibility, not private? It's necessary functionality for my website.

Comment: _“It's necessary functionality for my website”_ – in case you want to reward users for posts, please be aware that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Post` object has a `privacy` field, see:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post#fields